# Typecast by classType parameter

Tags: delphi

How can i make a `typecast` using the object `classType` parameter?

```
(obj as obj.classType).items[i]...//obj.classType = TList<myType>
```

This code is rejected by the compiler. But, moreover, I need to get access to the properties of the object, no matter what class (`TList`) it possesses:

```
system.classes.TList
system.generics.collections.TList<T>
```

In my program there is an object that actually belongs to the class `TList<T>`, and I am afraid that casting to a `system.classes.TList` type may cause some errors in my program.

Comment: You cannot typecast an object using its `ClassType` property like that. You need to specify the actual class statically that the property belongs to so you can cast the object to that class, eg: `(obj as TList<myType>).items[i]...`. Otherwise, you will have to use Enhanced RTTI via the `System.Rtti` unit classes to access the property you want. Even though `TList` and `TList<T>` have *similar* properties, they are not actually related to each other in any way, so you can't cast a `TList<T>` object to a `TList` and vice versa.

Comment: If you write in types section something like ` TMyList = System.Classes.TList;`, compiler will use exactly specified type.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to typecast like this. That is because Delphi is a statically typed language.

Imagibe you could write code like this:

```
(obj as obj.classType).items
```

Since the value if `obj.classType` is unknown at compile time, the compiler cannot, at compile time, know whether `items` even exists, never mind how to access it and so on.

As for your goal regarding list classes, the generic and non-generic list types do not share a common ancestor beyond `TObject`. What you are attempting is simply impossible.

Whatever your problem is, you'll need to find a different solution.

Comment: And if, for example, I need to call this code only for generics.`TList`, simply, in the process of execution, I do not know the type that is inside (`TList<T>`)? How to be in this case?

Comment: I don't understand the question you ask in that comment.

Comment: If we are talking only about `generics` of different types, and not about the usual type of `TList`, then how can I make a typecast for this type? For example, `(obj as TList <TMyClass>).items`, only instead of `TMyClass` at runtime there may be another class.

Comment: You can't do that either. You need help working out the solution to your problem, but instead you are offering your solutions which I have already explained don't work. I think this question is done now. If you still need help, that would be a new question where you should ask about the actual problem.